# Reading ext2 superblock into ext2_super_block struct questions

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I've seen some questions on reading the superblock of an ext2 partition, but I have some questions that weren't answered in these.
Here they go:
1. using read() to read from disk into a ext2_super_block struct should require that all the fields in the struct are compiled in the order they are presented in the code, as well as the necessity of there being no struct padding (or the correct struct padding). How is that guaranteed?
2. How does Linux behave when trying to read from a device when unprivileged? There must be an initial offset for the reads (a mapping, to be more precise, forbidding access to the first N bytes), because the program I wrote only works when running as root. Anyways, how does Linux behave in that situation?
3. Where can I find good documentation on working with ext2/ext3? So far I've been reading /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h and some random documents on the internet, but have found nothing complete yet.

I would also like to hear suggestions/corrections on the code below, which so far works fine on my machine (includes omitted for brevity, the program prints "ef53"):

```
int main() {
  int fd;
  char boot[1024];
  struct ext2_super_block super_block;

  fd = open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY);

  /* Reads the boot section and the superblock */
  read(fd, boot, 1024);
  read(fd, &super_block, sizeof(struct ext2_super_block));

  /* Prints the Magic Number */
  printf("%x\n", super_block.s_magic);

  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ext2fs is similar to UFS and FFS, so you can consult docs on those (though ext2 always has 1 fragment per block).

Answer (score 0):

> all the fields in the struct are compiled in the order they are presented in the code

I know no C compiler which reorders fields in structures. I don't think this is allowed by C standard.
For alingnemt and padding look at the declaration of the structure. There are some macros involved.

> How does Linux behave when trying to read from a device when unprivileged?

Lets ask `ls`:

```
j@linux:~> ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 15. Mai 17:51 /dev/sda
```

You can only read as root or if you are in `disk` group.

> Where can I find good documentation on working with ext2/ext3?

Use the source, luke. Don't forget that there is more than the linux kernel being able to read ext2/3.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't error checking the return value of open() and thought I was reading correctly from the FD, without even checking the permissions of /dev/sda1.. As for rearranging fields of a struct, "man gcc", look for -Wpadded and you will see that rearranging is possible.. It would be nice if we could somehow consult the standard (which I just found not to be free). Also, this also means that byte-endianness matters when reading, right? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some of your questions in my quest for answers.

1. The `ext2_super_block struct` is already setup to be in order/padded to spec. You can create your own or use the standard one.
2. The open() function will return less than 0 if there was an error and you can call `printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));` to print the error. If it returns something like "Permission denied" then use `sudo chmod 777 /dev/yourdevice` if in a Ubuntu terminal to grant permission to it.
3. I can't find too much documentation myself, I can pass you my code to open a device if that helps.

Comment: I have successfully read from the partition, listing directories and reading files and doing a lot more. I would still like to know how two machines with different byte-endianness would read the same superblock, and how it is guaranteed that the compiler won't reorder the fields in the struct. I have looked into /usr/src/linux/include/linux/ext2_fs.h and haven't found anything that tells the compiler to do so. Can you explain how this struct is setup to be in order/padded? This is the only thing keeping me from accepting your answer.

Comment: The superblock is stored in little-endian, not in system endianness: http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#DEF-SUPERBLOCK `All fields in the superblock (as in all other ext2 structures) are stored on the disc in little endian format, so a filesystem is portable between machines without having to know what machine it was created on.`

Comment: As for padding, here's GCC's man on `-Wpadded`: `Warn if padding is included in a structure, either to align an element of the structure or to align the whole structure. Sometimes when this happens it is possible to rearrange the fields of the structure to reduce the padding and so make the structure smaller.` I believe it should be read as _it is possible **for the programmer** (not the compiler) to rearrange the fields to reduce padding_. Especially since this is a warning and not an optimization directive.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <./linux/ext2_fs.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct ext2_super_block es;
int f;
char but[1024];

  f = open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY);
  read(f, but, 1024);  
  read(f, &es, sizeof(struct ext2_super_block));
  printf("El tamano de int es %d byts\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("El tamano de char es %d byts\n", sizeof(char));
  printf("Número de inodos: %d \n", es.s_inodes_count);
  printf("Número de bloques: %d \n", es.s_blocks_count); 
  printf("Número de bloques libres: %d \n", es.s_free_blocks_count); 
  printf("Número de inodos libres: %d \n", es.s_free_inodes_count);
  printf("Tamano del bloque: %d \n", es.s_log_block_size);
  printf("Bloques en un grupo: %d \n", es.s_blocks_per_group);
  printf("Fragmentos en un grupo: %d \n", es.s_frags_per_group);
  printf("NM: %x\n", es.s_magic);

return (0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but my problem is not reading info from the filesystem. I'm actually interested in how the C Standard's lack of standardization on struct memory layouts can compromise reading the partition with code compiled on different compilers or in different architectures.